# How does Codeigniter receive the ajax post data in controller without input type text and input post

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Here's code for Controller :

```
public function Update()
{
    $id_form = $this->input->post('id_form');
    $no_request = $this->input->post('no_request');

    $data = {
       "no_request" => $no_request,
       "date_ps" => date('d M Y')
    }

    return $this->db->where('id_form', $id_form);
    return $this->db->update('table', $data);
}
```

Here's code for View :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_form" id="id_form"></br>
<input type="text" name"no_request" id="no_request"></br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_update">Edit</a>
```

Here's code for Ajax :

```
$('#btn_update').on('click', function() {
  var id_form = $('#id_form').val();
  var no_request = $('#no_request').val();
  var date_ps = $(date_ps).val();

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?= site_url('Controller/Update') ?>",
     dataType: "JSON",
     data: {
       id_form: id_form,
       no_request: no_request,
       date_ps: date_ps
     },
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(date_ps);
     }
  })
}
```

But The result for `date_ps` is *undefined*, How can I get the date_ps value without having to undefined

Comment: why u want to pass "date_ps" throgh ajax

Comment: because I want the 'date_ps' field to be updated using ajax, can such methods not work?

Comment: where you have define date_ps name field in html ??

Comment: if you have defined **date_ps** in html , then in ajax u r accessing it wrong it should be     var date_ps = $('#date_ps').val();

Comment: in controller u r not using **date_ps** post variable. so that's why i asked you . why you want to pass that field, if you are not using it

Comment: i want pass the field  by auto, so I don't need to fill the fields in html, i want pass date_ps by auto in the controller

Comment: then pass it like this **var date_ps = "data you want to pass";**